# Foursquare OAuth suddenly not working

Tags: foursquare

I have a Foursquare app that I'm trying to get integrated into a website I'm working on, it has been working fine up to this point but suddenly trying to go the URL "https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate?client_id=[MY_APP_ID]&response_type=code&redirect_uri=[REDIRECT_URL]" is giving me an "invalid_token" error, which is strange to me because I haven't even gotten to the second part of the OAuth "dance". Am I missing something obvious? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're able to reproduce and are investigating. Thanks for the report!

Comment: We're pushing a fix to our servers now

Comment: This is now fixed. Thanks for the report!

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate endpoint. Try https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authorize instead.

Answer (score -2):

We just tweeted to @FoursquareAPI and @4sqSupport.  Its broken for us as well as IFTTT